# Passing a constant value to a stored procedure mapping in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm working on creating an Entity Framework model for our database tables, and for the most part, things are going pretty well. However, I'm running into a bit of an issue mapping the stored procedures. See, the homebuilt ORM that our company has been using tends to use one sproc for inserting and updating, and differentiats the operations by passing a bit valued parameter called `@IsInsert` (I know, don't get me started). Entity Framework seems to expect separate sprocs for inserting and updating, so I figure that all I have to do is tell EF "pass `true` for this parameter when you're using it as an insert, `false` if it's an update". However, at least according to the designer UI, it doesn't seem to give me the option for any mapping other than fields on the entity object. Is there a way to pass a constant value (boolean `true` or `false`) to a sproc mapping in EF4?

Comment: man that sucks - how about creating two wrapper stored procs: SPROC_Ins, SPROC_Upd - these are the ones called by EF. And these sprocs would simply pass the param to the to the dodgy proc?

Comment: That occurred to me, but I would really prefer to make as few DB changes as possible. Shockingly, our DB deployment process isn't the smoothest in the world.

Comment: So you're trying to re-use the same sprocs? Why not just map both insert and update operations to the same sproc and then add an IsInsert property to your model. Not ideal to have to do that but should allow you to re-use the sprocs (if that was your original goal).

Comment: Call me a purist, but I really don't like polluting my domain objects with logic meant just to facilitate persistence. Also, that would require that the IsInsert property be set manually for each object, which seems to me is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be to use context.executestorequery(query) and keep it how it was before.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't that mean having to manually invoke that method each time? That is, the nice thing about EF's sproc mapping would be that I could have it prepare and call the necessary sprocs for me itself whenever necessary, so that I can just say entityCollection.Save() (or whatever) and not have to worry about setting up the query, right?

Comment: You have a special case for your query's.  You can use context.executestorequery<T>(query) and what you will get back are strongly typed entities that are tracked by entity framework.  so when you modify one of the entities you received all you have to do is context.save() and it will save any entities that were modified.

Comment: But the `query` parameter would have to be prepared manually, right? E.g.: context.ExecuteStoreQuery("EXEC MyUpdateInsertSproc @IsInsert = 1...") (or something to that effect). Also, won't context.Save() call the mapped sprocs automatically?